# How to put X mark at the top of box in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to integrate threejs for my project, and I get this problem where I cannot position the **X** mark at the top/bottom of the boxes. What I currently have is the **X** mark is not positioning dynamically and also I noticed that the **X** mark is a bit big than the expected result. Please see my code below.

**Current code**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonjieviduya/42onmv7y/1)

```
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r127/build/three.module.js'

function generate3DBox(selector, angle, boxDepth, boxWidth, boxHeight) {

  let allowedAngles = [
    'no-overstack',
    'no-understack'
  ]

  if (allowedAngles.indexOf(angle) < 0) {
    console.log("Angle is incorrect")
    return false
  }

  const canvas = document.querySelector(selector)
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas,
    antialias: true
  })

  const canvasWidth = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width
  const canvasHeight = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height
  const minSize = Math.min(...[boxDepth, boxWidth, boxHeight])
  const maxSize = Math.max(...[boxDepth, boxWidth, boxHeight])

  const aspect = canvasWidth / canvasHeight
  const fov = 75
  const near = 0.1
  const far = 1000

  let cameraZoom = 1
  let cameraPosition = {
    left: canvasWidth / -2,
    right: canvasWidth / 2,
    top: canvasHeight / 2,
    bottom: canvasHeight / -2
  }

  const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    cameraPosition.left,
    cameraPosition.right,
    cameraPosition.top,
    cameraPosition.bottom,
    near,
    far
  )

  camera.position.z = maxSize + minSize
  // console.log(camera.position)
  cameraZoom = 45 / maxSize //0.45
  camera.zoom = cameraZoom

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

  const scene = new THREE.Scene()
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xe0e0e0)

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth)

  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff4500
  }) // greenish blue

  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  //console.log(cube.position.z -= 25)

  var edge = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(cube.geometry)
  var edgeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    linewidth: 1
  })
  var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(edge, edgeMaterial)



  scene.add(cube, wireframe)

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    let rotationX = 0
    let rotationY = 0
    let rotationZ = 0

    if (angle == 'no-overstack') {
    
         const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial( {
            color: 0xff0000,
            linewidth: 1,
            scale: 1,
            dashSize: 3,
            gapSize: 1,
        });

        const points1 = [];
        const points2 = [];

        points1.push( new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, 0 ) );
        points1.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );

        points2.push( new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0 ) );
        points2.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ) );

        let lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points1);
        let lineGeometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points2);


        const line1 = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry, lineMaterial );
        const line2 = new THREE.Line( lineGeometry2, lineMaterial );

        line1.position.x = 7
        line2.position.x = -7
        
        scene.add(line1, line2)
      
        rotationX = 0
        rotationY = 0
        rotationZ = 0
    }

    if (angle == 'no-understack') {

      rotationX = 0
      rotationY = 0
      rotationZ = 0
    }

    cube.rotation.x = rotationX
    cube.rotation.y = rotationY
    cube.rotation.z = rotationZ

    wireframe.rotation.x = rotationX
    wireframe.rotation.y = rotationY
    wireframe.rotation.z = rotationZ

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
  }

  animate()
}

generate3DBox('.no-overstack', 'no-overstack', 5, 4, 3)
generate3DBox('.no-understack', 'no-understack', 5, 4, 3)
```

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: If this is the final expected result, then you don't need `Three.js`, a simple `HTML` `CSS` combination will do ... if you insist on using `Three` then it's just a matter of playing with positions, rotations, conditions and events ... one last point you should move the creation of lines outside of the animation loop, in your code you are creating new Lines with `lineGeometry` and `lineMaterial` on each rendered frame.

Comment: Can you give an example based on the fiddle code above?